# What is the difference between activemqconnectionfactory and pooledconnectionfactory?

Tags: activemq-classic

As the title said, What is their difference and how to make a choice?
I wonder is there something same as each other?
If I want to make a keep-alive connection? That is said once I connect to activemq server,
I can using the connection to send/receive message whenever I want. I think I can call it 
daemonProducer or daemonConsumer. Can activemq implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ActiveMQConnectionFactory creates ActiveMQ Connections.  The PooledConnectionFactory pools Connections.  If you only need to create one Connection and keep it around for a long time you don't need to pool.  If you tend to create many Connection instances over time then Pooling is better as connecting is a heavy operation and can be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more question, Both the ActiveMQ Connection and the Connection from pool can keep them for long time running? and the session will always valid and not expired?

Comment: Well you should have a look at the API for PooledConnectionFactory.  By default the pooled version will Idle out old connections after some time of non-use.  The ActiveMQ connection created from its factory is valid until you call close() or it is no longer referenced.